# How to limit the numbers of records fetched from couchdb using view

Tags: couchdb

I have created a view and it contains thousands of records I want get only 10 or 20 at a time ,for this I tried to use **http://localhost:5984/recipes/_design/recipes/_view/by_recipe?limit=2** which is not working ,Still it is giving me entire data.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to use `limit` in combination with `skip`, according to these docs: https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_view_API

Answer (score 0):

It is better if you use the startkey and limit to avoid slow response in large number of documents. In the same URL above, you will find this.
For example:
http://127.0.0.1:5984/mybd/_design/myviews/_view/get?startkey="blabla1"&limit=2