# CoachDb limit between two values

Tags: couchdb

I am using CouchDB 1.6.

I have a view that returns almost 30000 documents.

In the other hand I have a service, whose mane is `Kettle transformations`, that calls the view using  order to get and work with the documents

> myserver/mybasedate/_design/masterdata/_view/bytype?key=["master"]

The problem I have is that returns too many documents so my service goes unresponsive.

So I am thinking about create small documents parts . I have been testing whit `?limit`

> myserver/mybasedate/_design/masterdata/_view/bytype?key=["master"]?limit=5000

but I don't get what I want. I need something like

Get the 5000 first documents.
Get the documents >5000 and <10000

Does anyone know how I can do that?

this answer is about how to use `limit`
[How to limit the numbers of records fetched from couchdb using view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31915327/how-to-limit-the-numbers-of-records-fetched-from-couchdb-using-view)
For example I want to get the documents between 10 and 50 , if I use limit I can see the 10 first or 50 firts , but not a range >10 && <50

In the other hand I am not sure how to use skip

> _design/masterdata/_view/bytype?key=["master"]&limit=2&skip=0&skip=1

give me 2 result

> _design/masterdata/_view/bytype?key=["master"]&skip=45&limit=50

returns 50 documents

Comment: Not related to your question, but you should be aware, CouchDB 1.6 has a _serious security flaw_, which can allow practically anyone root access to your server. You should upgrade to 1.7 immediately.

Comment: To answer your question: use `skip`, as [documented](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/ddoc/views.html#api-ddoc-view).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to limit the numbers of records fetched from couchdb using view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31915327/how-to-limit-the-numbers-of-records-fetched-from-couchdb-using-view)

Comment: thanks, I have added more info in my question

Comment: It's still a duplicate. If you want documents 10-50, set skip=10, limit=40.

Comment: _design/masterdata/_view/bytype?key=["master"]&skip=45&limit=50 returns 50 documents :(

Comment: Yes, exactly as documented and as expected. You said limit 50, so you get 50. How many do you want?

Comment: skip 45 & limit 50 = 5 ?

Comment: So you want a limit of 5 documents? If so, set limit=5, obviously.

Comment: Ok get it, in other words :  show me 50 documents but skip the 45 first ones . thanks